# Apply shader to model-viewer using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shader, webgl

I'm using Google's [ModelViewer](https://modelviewer.dev/) for a WebAR project.

I have a vue.js project and I have a component that is loading the model with the `<model-viewer>` attribute. I have also installed [vue-gl](https://vue-gl.github.io/) with npm just in case it's needed.

I'd like to know if I can (and what do I need to) apply custom shaders on the 3D model of the ModelViewer.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**To adjust the shading** you must add **lighting to the scene**

**Like This:**

https://modelviewer.dev/examples/lighthouse.html

**or this:**

https://modelviewer.dev/examples/tester.html

you can use **Model Viewer Editor**:
https://modelviewer.dev/editor/

This document will help you:

https://modelviewer.dev/docs/index.html#entrydocs-lightingandenv-attributes-shadowIntensity

Comment: hey! thanks for your response, but that's not the answer I'm looking for. I didn't mean to apply lights and shadows to the model, that's related to the properties of the materials of the model. What I mean is to apply "shaders" (vertex shader and fragment shader) using the gpu, like with webgl.